# When including maps into the layout application crashes

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a layout which should have google maps. But when i try to include the map the application crashes. Without maps it's working fine.

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_contactus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_contactus"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_address"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_telephone1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_tp1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_telephone2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_tp2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_email"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filmhall_facilities"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cinema_filmhall_facility"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />






</LinearLayout>
```

when i remove the xml code for maps,it's working.otherwise not

my logcat

```
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at com.fortuna.cinemalk.TheaterDetailFragment.onCreateView(TheaterDetailFragment.java:24)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
08-06 10:43:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(28210):    ... 19 more
08-06 10:43:12.986: E/android.os.Debug(2381): !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
08-06 10:43:21.535: E/ViewRootImpl(2381): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
08-06 10:43:21.575: E/InputDispatcher(2381): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-06 10:43:22.196: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2381): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
08-06 10:43:32.935: E/Watchdog(2381): !@Sync 1245
```

Map class

```
package com.fortuna.cinemalk;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Map extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is your logcat said?

Comment: show your logcat manifest and Activity code utilizing the maps

Comment: there i included logcat

Comment: extend fragmentActivity not Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem:**

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

You cant cast a `MapFragment` to the `Fragment` of the native android which will result to `ClassCastException` instead cast it with `MapFragment` when you are trying to use the `android:id="@+id/map"`

```
GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

EDIT:

the `MapFragment` is an old version of map I would recommend SupportMapFragment for a newer version of it.

```
<fragment 
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: i changed it to SupportMapFragment.But there's still an error

"Cant cast from fragment to SupportMapFragment"

Comment: private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
 
            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following Permissions to your Manifest.xml file.

```
<permission
        android:name="com.fortuna.cinemalk.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Before

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion=".."
        android:targetSdkVersion=".." />
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: I just suggest the user to check the permissions

Comment: @KP Ya i know but without any *Manifest* posted how can you suggested? There are many reasons for the errors.